# Is it possible for a `NoClassDefFoundError` to be flaky and only occur sometimes?

Tags: java, gradle, teamcity, noclassdeffounderror

I have already googled this issue and understand that it means the class is found at compile time but not at Runtime.

I've also already done research here: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

In my context, I have this exception running as a TeamCity build. One of the builds failed with this exception but then passed the subsequent builds. The builds before it also passed.

I'm absolutely confused here.

1.) If it was bc it wasn't in the class path, why is it would suddenly fail in one build? Same as the reason being the jar having a missing dependency.
2.) I didn't see `ExceptionInInitializerError` anywhere.
3.) There weren't any new changes included in this particular build which further confuses me so I don't think it was caused by another change.

If it also helps, I'm using gradle to compile everything and these are cucumber tests.

Comment: Maybe a corrupted dependency download from maven repo in your TeamCity build?

Comment: I have sometimes come across this problem if I have several Classes and within perhaps two of them I have public methods containing the very same signature. By removing one of the methods or changing the signature in some way (perhaps the method name or a parameter Data Type) then doing a Clean & Build tends to clear things up. But...that's just my experience with the error.

Comment: Is the class in question present in some JAR at run time?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError can also be thrown if class static initializer (static field or static section) throws exception.